# A feature rich JavaScript IDE environment?

Tags: javascript, ide, editor

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2008 to edit .js files with, and it has decent support but I want more...

I like the VS syntax highlighting and auto-indentation features but additionally would like advanced features like: contextual info and help, collapsible JavaScript blocks, implicit symbol understanding for searching, refactoring and that kind of thing; also warnings and errors for the js code.

Suggestions?

**Edit**: ooops... for the Windows platform. I see some Eclipse answers already and that's fine as I'll install Eclipse on Windows.

**Purpose:** I want the tool to be feature rich to aid my understanding of what's happening because JavaScript can get quite obtuse when jQuery is being used. Actually, it can be quite obtuse to understand regardless. Plus the additional (non-jQuery) branching for different browsers and tweaks. It can take a long time to wade through.

Comment: Not feature-rich.  Marginally relevant: http://tide4javascript.com/

Comment: WebStorm from www.jetbrains.com is excellent for JavaScript, because it supports ECMAScript 5, understands JsDoc perfectly (inheritance and all). It's the only IDE that actually does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever try Aptana?

http://www.aptana.org/

Answer (score 4):

I use Komodo Edit ([link](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/)) or Aptana.

Comment: Komodo has a very nice interface but when I told it to reformat some complex jQuery it broke some of it by breaking lines where it shouldn't have. Only in a couple of cases but still Aptana handled the same script without problem.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveState Komodo Edit works here too. See my answer just posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472620/good-html-css-php-editor-that-is-free-and-multi-platform/2472646#2472646).

Comment: Indeed you are correct about the jQuery stuff. That just happens to be what I tried first.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains is working on a promising Web/Javascript IDE called WebStorm. They currently have a public preview out:

http://www.jetbrains.com/webide/index.html

It has some interesting features:

- Javascript refactoring
- DOM-Based, Browser-Specific Completion
- Code Navigation and Usages Search
- Code Inspections and Quick-Fixes
- JavaScript Debugger Based on Mozilla
- Frameworks Support (jQuery, Prototype, ...)

Answer (score 0):

My choice is NetBeanse (as IDE).

But more more often i prefer emacs

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA by jetbrains is pretty good for javascript:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ajax.html